# How to associate apple payment notification with my custom payment records?

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

**I want to add subscriptions** to my app. I already have in-app-purchase working but I have a problem: **the server-to-server payment notification have no data related to my system**, so I don't know which record I have to update when notification arrives.

I'm trying to follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_status_update_notifications#3162176).

**I want a flow like this image** but I can't find some param in the payment API that allows me to add a `bill_id`.

[image: desired flow]

Comment: ApplePay is different to IAP. Which are you using?  Your flow doesn't look right for IAP.

Comment: @Paulw11 i updated the description, i'm using this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_status_update_notifications#3162176

Comment: The flow you have drawn isn't how it works. You initiate purchase in device. You then send the receipt from the device to your server for validation.  Once your app has received confirmation from your server that it has validated the receipt and activated the subscription the device completes the transaction with StoreKit. The Apple to your server communication is an optional flow you can use. You can correlate data from the receipt provided when the user made the original purchase with the receipt provided by Apple to your server to identify which subscription is being renewed etc.

Comment: @Paulw11 something like this?  user pays > get receipt > validate from my server against apple server > update user account > listen notifications of next status updates like renew, cancel, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, you can't add your custom key to the payment process (like others payment gateways allows), you have to associate the `receipt` to your system to track the user's bill. You have to use the `validate receipt` Apple's api to consider the payment done and valid. So the payment process is `sync`, you haven't to wait any notification to consider the payment done, but you have to listen notifications to get notified when a subscription is canceled or renewed. Here is a graphic of the solution.

[image: the f*#! solution]

Comment: Currect if I am wrong.. but in this flow anyone who have the recipt can actualy use it as a paid member, right? What does bind it with a specific user?

Comment: check the flow, your server is in the middle and you can associate the recipt with a specific user in your database. This process is only at buying time. But yes, I guess if you can steal the recipt from another user and use it before he/she register it you should be able to set your membership as paid. I think that's almost impossible bc the flow happens in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use appAccountToken when create purchase:

- [appAccountToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/appaccounttoken)
- [create purchase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption?changes=la)
- [server notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/unified_receipt/latest_receipt_info)